# How to set file permissions while creating ISO file using iso9660-maven-plugin? I am getting error message : "*** Permissions list is empty!"

Tags: maven, iso

How to set file permissions while creating ISO file using iso9660-maven-plugin?
I am getting error message : "*** Permissions list is empty!"

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got a solution: Disable RockRidge

```
                    <configuration>
                        <enableRockRidge>false</enableRockRidge>
                    </configuration>
```